# What is the Azure Data Lake Storage Connection String For "Data Lake Store"

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-storage-emulator

I'm trying to write unit tests for my Azure Data Lake Storage (v1) repository against AzureStorageEmulator. Is this possible? If so, what do I use for the parameters of create client? Also, where on my file system will it store this data?

```
var client = AdlsClient.CreateClient("accountFqdn????", "token???");
```

When I open "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer", I see "Data Lake Store (Preview)->(Development)" as an option, so I assume this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Azure Store Emulator is for:

> [Azure Blob, Queue, and Table services for development purposes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator)

It isn't unfortunately for emulating Data Lake Store (at least at the time of writing, but now that Data Lake Store Gen2 is backed by blob storage, this may change).

The closet thing to an emulator is the [LocalRunHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-sdk), but that is for locally testing U-SQL rather than connecting to data lake store.

However, if you are looking to write unit tests (rather than end-to-end tests / integration tests), you may wish to look at the [MockAdlsClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.mockadlsfilesystem.mockadlsclient?view=azure-dotnet) which has the same API as AdlsClient but works in memory instead.